# Why does "polymer build" throw the error "File not found with singular glob"?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, polymer-cli

After running `polymer build` in my project's root director using the [Polymer CLI](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli) 1.1.0, I get this error:

```
info:    Clearing build/ directory...
error:   Uncaught exception: Error: File not found with singular glob: /home/willie/Projects/World History Final Project/src/passport-app/passport-app.html
error:   Error: File not found with singular glob: /home/willie/Projects/World History Final Project/src/passport-app/passport-app.html
    at Glob.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/glob-stream/index.js:41:11)
    at Glob.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Glob.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Glob._finish (/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/glob-stream/node_modules/glob/glob.js:172:8)
    at done (/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/glob-stream/node_modules/glob/glob.js:159:12)
    at Glob._processSimple2 (/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/glob-stream/node_modules/glob/glob.js:652:12)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/glob-stream/node_modules/glob/glob.js:640:10
    at Glob._stat2 (/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/glob-stream/node_modules/glob/glob.js:736:12)
    at lstatcb_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/glob-stream/node_modules/glob/glob.js:728:12)
```

I want to know why this keeps happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Polymer CLI is designed to build apps using the REPL [app shell architecture](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/11/app-shell). In your [`polymer.json`](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/tools/polymer-json) file, you must define any "fragments" that are lazy-loaded. After adding the fragments to the file, running `polymer build` in the directory containing the config file.

```
{
  "entrypoint": "index.html",
  "shell": "src/passport-app.html",
  "fragments": [
    //This is where you messed up.
    "src/passport-home.html",
    "src/passport-introduction.html",
    "src/passport-404.html",
    "src/passport-economy.html",
    "src/passport-news.html",
    "src/passport-immigration.html",
    "src/passport-culture.html"
  ],
  "sources": [
    "src/**/*",
    "images/**/*",
    "bower.json"
  ],
  "extraDependencies": [
    "manifest.json",
    "bower_components/webcomponentsjs/*.js"
  ],
  "lint": {
    "rules": [
      "polymer-2"
    ]
  },
  "builds": [
    {
      "preset": "es6-bundled"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for `extraDependencies`. Default Polymer `includeDependencies` didn't work.